# sort an ArrayList of object using compareTo() method of the interface Comparable

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, collections

I have to write a method to sort an ArrayList in Java. I have a Dog class where i decleared an ArrayList of Collars of the dog. I want to write a method to sort this list with the name of the color of the collars in alphabetical order.

```
public class Dog {
private String name;
private int age;
private List<Collar> list;

public Dog(String name, int age){
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.list = new ArrayList<Collar>();
}
```

then in the Dog class I have written the method:

```
public List<Collar> sortList(){
    List<Collar> list2 = new ArrayList<Collar>();
    list2.addAll(this.list);
    Collections.sort(list2);
    return list2;
}
```

and I've used the Comparable interface:

```
public class Collar implements Comparable<Collar>{
private String color;
private int dimension;

/*Constructor,getters and setters*/

@Override
public int compareTo(Collare o) {
    return this.color.compareTo(o.color);
}
```

the problem is that all this code doesn't work and I don't know why, infact if i write a test:

```
@Test
public void test_SortList() {
    Dog dog = new Dog("Bobby",1);
    List<Collar> list = new ArrayList<Collar>();
    Collar c3 = new Collar("Azure",2);
    Collar c2 = new Collar("Blue",5);
    Collar c1 = new Collar("Cyan",1);
    list.add(c1);
    list.add(c3);
    list.add(c2);
    dog.sortList();
    assertEquals("Azure",list.get(0).getColor());
    assertEquals("Blue",list.get(1).getColor());
    assertEquals("Cyan",list.get(2).getColor());
}
```

it fails. Can anybody help me and tell me where is my mistake? Thank's.

I have tried to do this:

```
@Test
public void test_SortList() {
    Dog dog = new Dog("Bobby",1);
    List<Collar> list = new ArrayList<Collar>();
    Collar c3 = new Collar("Azure",2);
    Collar c2 = new Collar("Blue",5);
    Collar c1 = new Collar("Cyan",1);
    list.add(c1);
    list.add(c3);
    list.add(c2);
    list = dog.sortList();
    assertEquals("Azure",list.get(0).getColor());
    assertEquals("Blue",list.get(1).getColor());
    assertEquals("Cyan",list.get(2).getColor());
}
```

but it still fails. It gives me indexOutOfBoundsException.

Why if i do:

```
list.add(c1);
list.add(c3);
list.add(c2);
list = dog.sortList();
assertEquals(3,list.size());
```

it fails and it says that size is 0?

i got why it says 0, it is because when i do `list = dog.sortList()` i'm no more linking to the old list.
So i tried this:

```
@Test
public void test_SortList() {
    Dog dog = new Dog("Bobby",1);
    List<Collar> list = new ArrayList<Collar>();
    Collar c3 = new Collar("Azure",2);
    Collar c2 = new Collar("Blue",5);
    Collar c1 = new Collar("Cyan",1);
    list.add(c1);
    list.add(c3);
    list.add(c2);
    List<Collar>list2 = dog.sortList();
    list2.addAll(list);
    assertEquals("Azure",list2.get(0).getColor());
    assertEquals("Blue",list2.get(1).getColor());
    assertEquals("Cyan",list2.get(2).getColor());
}
```

but it still does not work.

I solved it. I post my solution in case someone needs it :

i have passed by parameter the list in the method:

```
public List<Collar> sortList(List<Collar> list2){
    list2.addAll(this.list);
    Collections.sort(list2);
    return list2;
}
```

then in the test i did this:

```
@Test
public void test_SortList() {
    Dog dog = new Dog("Bobby",1);
    List<Collar> list = new ArrayList<Collar>();
    Collar c3 = new Collar("Azure",2);
    Collar c2 = new Collar("Blue",5);
    Collar c1 = new Collar("Cyan",1);
    list.add(c1);
    list.add(c3);
    list.add(c2);
    dog.sortList(list);
    assertEquals("Azure",list.get(0).getColor());
    assertEquals("Blue",list.get(1).getColor());
    assertEquals("Cyan",list.get(2).getColor());
}
```

or probably i could just have added a collar to the list in the Dog class.

Answer (score 1):

`dog.sortList()` returns a new list. It does not modify the list held by the `dog`.

In addition to that your local variable `List<Collar> list = new ArrayList<Collar>();` is completely unrelated to `dog.list`. Adding collars to `list` has no effect on `dog.list`.

You need to

- check the list returned by `dog.sortList()`, and
- have some way to access the `dog.list` to insert the collars (I would probably pass the collars into the constructor -- assuming it makes sense for the Dog to know about the collar list in the first place, otherwise the `sort` method should probably not be on `Dog` at all).

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new instance of list in `sortList` method. This means that you are not sorting on original `list` instance which you have supplied to dog instance.

There are two ways to solve this problem:

- Get the new list returned by your method and assert on the same. You would need to do the following in your main method:

  ```
  List<Collar> collars = dog.sortList();
  assertEquals("Azure",collars.get(0).getColor());
  //other asserts
  ```
- Instead of creating new list, you could just use `list` instance and apply `sort` on that instance itself in `sortList` method.

Comment: "you are not sorting on original list instance which you have supplied to dog instance". In fact, OP did not supply the dog with a list instance at all...

Comment: good point @Thilo i assumed the way he pasted code in chunks he might have setter method to set the list.